# Prove $v,w\in Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$ is linearly independent when $p=2$ and dependent when $p=3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, congruences

I need to prove that $\{v=(6,9),w=(7,8)\}\in Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$ is linearly independent when $p=2$ and linearly dependent when $p=3$.
The problem is my freshman algebra course did not cover rings and I'm a bit lost.

My approach to the problem has been trying to find $a_1,a_2\in Z$ such that $a_1 6+a_2 7 \equiv 0\mod 2$ and $a_1 9+a_2 8 \equiv 0\mod 2$ ,that is:$a_1 6+a_2 7=2k$ and $a_1 9+a_2 8=2k'$ for some $k,k'\in Z$.
But I don't seem to get to anything, is this approach bad?
Another thing, is there any way to find all the valors of $p$ for which the set is linearly dependent?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the mod 3 case, use $1$ times the first plus $0$ times the second.  In the mod $2$ case we are looking at $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p=2$, $v=(0,1)$  and  $w=(1,0)$ . Then  $a.v +b.w =0$  implies $(a,b)=(0,0)$  for  which  to  hold  both  $a=0$  and  $b=0$  must  hold.

For  $p=3$ , $v=(0,0)$  and  $w=(1,2)$.  Now , you  know  that  for  any  vector  space  ,  any  subset  containing  the  $0$  vector  is  linearly  dependant .  So  the  set  $\{(0,0),(1,2)\}$  is  linearly  dependant. Or  more  precisely ,  $0.w + 1.v = (0,0)$  holds  for $p=3$.